# Can you install NPM and Git under a standard user account?

Tags: git, package-management

Currently all users in my environment run as standard users.  We now have developers starting that will need access to tools such as NPM and Git.

Is it possible to install these tools and limit to the user account?

The installers/packages appear to install globally which would imply they would also need sudo access.

Answer (score 1):

I have never had to invoke `sudo` when using `git`, besides during the install process.

For `npm`, you can configure it to install global packages in a directory your standard user has full access to using [this guide](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md).